# How to find the probability that $|X-Y|=0$?

Tags: binomial-distribution

So I have $X$, a $Bin(5,0.5)$ variable and $Y$, a $Bin(7,0.5)$ variable. I have to find $P[|X-Y|=0]$. 
According to my understanding, this probability is equivalent to $P[X=Y]$,
which is equal to 
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^5 P[X=k,Y=k]$$

I took the upper limit of of the sum as 5 and not 7, since those probabilities are zero anyway. Is this method correct?

Comment: Looks like a decent way to solve the problem, if you ask me. There may be some clever simplification hiding somewhere, but your solution is not terribly long the way it is, so I wouldn't worry too much about looking for one.

Comment: Cool,mate. Thank you!

Comment: yes that's the approach

Answer (score 1):

Let $X\sim\mathsf{Bin}(n,p)$ and $Y\sim\mathsf{Bin}(n,q)$. Then
\begin{align}
\mathbb P (|X-Y|=0) &= \mathbb P (X=Y)\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n \mathbb P(X=i,Y=i)\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n \mathbb P(X=i)\mathbb P(Y=i)\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n \binom ni p^i(1-p)^{n-i}\binom ni q^i (1-p)^{n-i}\\
&= (1-p)^n (1-q)^n \, _2F_1\left(-n,-n;1;\frac{p q}{(p-1) (q-1)}\right)
\end{align}
where ${}_{2}F_{1}$ denotes a hypergeometric function. In the case where $n=5$ and $p=q=\frac12$ this reduces to 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^5 \binom 5 i^2 \left(\frac12\right)^{10} = \frac{63}{256}.
$$